# Facebook Comments with Ember Views in Subroute

Tags: facebook, ember.js

I am trying to add the Facebook comment plugin to one of my subroutes, but the problem is that it is only shown when I refresh the page. As soon as I navigate somewhere else (= the view in which I added the snippet is removed) it is gone. Meaning when I navigate back to the same route, the Facebook Plugin is not reinitialized.

Is there a way to prevent it from being destroyed or maybe do some "FB.Init()" on route activation?

Comment: Without knowing very much about interacting with Facebook, this sounds like something that would be best wrapped in a [component](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/). A component would ensure that any setup/teardown is run whenever it's inserted/removed from the DOM.

Comment: I know that I could wrap it something the problem is more, what kind of setup/teardown is necessary for the FB stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using XFBML you can call

`FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));`

Or call it without parameters, to do it on the entire page.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using XFBML. Should I?

Comment: I could be wrong but I think that works for the current method of directly embedding likes/share/comment